# Can't install KDE destop on ubuntu 20.04 WSL

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 just installed from Microsoft Store in Windows 11.

I ran this command:

```
sudo apt install kde-full
```

[image: default display manager selection in dialog, sddm and gdm3 available]

After a long time installing, I clicked the sddm option as the tutorial said. But instead of the pretty interface of KDE, I can only see the simple black frame as before. As if nothing happened.

I don't know how to try to launch the KDE that is seemingly installed.

What can I do to fix this?

[image: terminal interface with prompt]

Comment: https://www.most-useful.com/kde-plasma-on-wsl.html

Comment: After doing those steps in the website. I still can't get access to the GUI. It went smoothly when I am installing. But it simply didn't show up after all these steps. Is windows11 capable to install KDE desktop?